# Is there a way to disable the wysiwyg editor when editing mail templates?

Tags: email, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add the "shortlink" html schema so my users on gmail can have the direct link to RSVP to the event or confirm their signature for the petition

Unfortunately, the editor on civicrm fubar the html to the point gmail can't recognise it anymore

Is this possible to disable the editor only when editing the mail template? So my users still have the wysiwyg editor when composing their mail, just the admins being able to write nice html templates without having the html editor messing up

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Source button in the editor, which allows you to directly modify the html?

Comment: I did, but then the editor still kicks in and reformat it and decides to add spans and reshuffle some tags around unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Editor can be disabled completely by the following

Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences.
CKEditor  can be changed to TextArea

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/

---

**For specify Action**

Editor can be disabled before editing the template using SQL

civicrm_setting table holds the CKEditor setting

Id: -         11

Group name: - CiviCRM Preferences

Name: -        editor_id

Value: - s:1:"2";

If the value is made null then it changes to Text Area and later it can be changed back to CKEditor

But, any member accessing the Editor at the every moment like in contact summary screen for creating PDF at the same time cannot view Editor till this is been changed -

Comment: I'm editing the question to clarify: I want to disable only when editing the templates, the rest should stay the same