# WYSIWYG Editor Permissions

Tags: civicontribute

In the online contribution section when we enable Tell A friend as a option we noticed that the option for an anonymous user only shows in a WYSIWYG Editor format. This is high risk and we would like to avoid it by only allowing admins to use the WYSIWYG Editor. However, I only see one option in the Customise Data section whichs says use the WYSIWYG Editor or not i.e. CKeditor, TinyMCE and Text area.

Is there a way to control access based on a users role.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link

[Is there a way to disable the wysiwyg editor when editing mail templates?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6337/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-wysiwyg-editor-when-editing-mail-templates)

you need to disable the Editor before user access the editor page

Comment: Hi Ramesh.. I don't think the link answers the question. In the Tell a Friend Page it always shows in HTML. We can disable to Text Area but how do we relate it to Drupal roles or anonymous vs signed in users?

Comment: this is bit hard seriously when you provide the link for an user you need text and for admin you need Editor but we don't have different setting for this - but still if you default it to text and whenever admin is using it you can change that to editor and roll back to text area once job is done - this i guess you can do with an extension -

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. However, it is not feasible as a solution. In Drupal for example we have Roles and options in CK Editor to setup which roles get or are seen what type of editors. To me giving HTML to anonymous users is not good practice and it should be editable. I will leave this open in case anyone else has suggestions. Cheers.